Passing argument to method on COM Dispatch in Rust with windows-rs
I am trying to Invoke the method Move on an Outlook MailItem Dispatch object and need to provide a MAPIFolder as an argument.
I am able to call/get other methods/properties that do not require any arguments, but all attempts to provide arguments have resulted in various errors.
From their GUIDs I know that email is _MailItem and folder is MAPIFolder.
I am also able to retrieve the dispid of _MailItem.Move.
From the docs, Move is supposed to take a single MAPIFolder as argument.
This example results in HRESULT 0x80020009 which is "exception", and the description is "Property is read-only". I've no idea which property of which object this is referring to.
let email : IDispatch = ...;
let folder : IDispatch = ...;

let args = vec![VARIANT::from(folder)];

let dispparams = DISPPARAMS {
    rgvarg : args.as_mut_ptr() as *mut VARIANT,
    rgdispidNamedArgs : null_mut() as *mut i32,
    cArgs : 1,
    cNamedArgs : 0,
};

let mut result = EXCEPINFO::default();
let mut exception = VARIANT::new();

unsafe {
email.Invoke(
    move_dispid, // Method ID
    &GUID::zeroed(), // reserved
    LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, // constant, 0x0400
    0x01 | 0x08, // constant, Method | ByRef
    &dispparams as *const DISPPARAMS,
    Some(&mut result as *mut VARIANT),
    Some(&mut exception as *mut EXCEPINFO),
    None,
)
};


What is the argument variant type? Is it vt_dispatch? Or vt_variant?

@DmitryStreblechenko I believe the VARIANT created from the folder dispatch should have vt 9, so vt_dispatch? Should it be vt_variant? The Outlook docs are not clear on this.

vt_dispatch should be good. Are you sure folder is not null?

@DmitryStreblechenko Yes. I am able to get its Name property and its GUID.

Why do you think Mover wants named args rather than regular args? Do you get a different error?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I'd rather continue the discussion here for other developers benefit...

@DmitryStreblechenko My bad. I thought the chat was publicly visible and just went with SO's advice.
I thought the error from using positional arguments was "Missing argument", but actually it was HRESULT(0x80020005), which is disp type mismatch. So I was wrong, but don't know why I receive mismatch.

The problem was adding the ByRef flag to the Invoke call. It should have only been DISPATCH_METHOD.
Other difficulties were:

Retrieving the Application Dispatch object by initializing an IUnknown and then casting it to IDispatch. This caused random exceptions which did not occur when initializing as IDispatch directly.
Trying to use named arguments instead of positional arguments. It seems that most functions just use positional arguments.

